# Python Minecraft Launcher Lib File Not Found Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I wanted to create a Minecraft Launcher using Python today, but the game cannot be started.

My Code:

```
import minecraft_launcher_lib
import subprocess

minecraft_directory = "C:\\Users\\Mert KAPLANDAR\\AppData\\Roaming\\.minecraft"

options = minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.generate_test_options()

minecraft_command = minecraft_launcher_lib.command.get_minecraft_command("1.8.9", minecraft_directory, options)

subprocess.call(minecraft_command)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\Desktop\launcher.py", line 10, in <module>
    subprocess.call(str(minecraft_command))
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 349, in call
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as p:
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Mert KAPLANDAR\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mert Kaplander, I would believe the error might be because you don't have that version of Minecraft installed. You can check with the following method:

```py
minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.get_installed_versions(minecraft_dir)
```

example:

```py
import subprocess
import minecraft_launcher_lib
from colorama import Fore, init

for version in minecraft_launcher_lib.utils.get_installed_versions(minecraft_dir):
    print(Fore.GREEN+ f"{version}")
```

Other than that, your code is an exact copy from the documentation. So I don't see an other error.